# Class diagram for a mini JEE project

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I want to start a project in JEE and I need to confirm about my class diagram.  I need to know if the methods used are correct and if the composition I used is correct or not.

This is my class diagram:

[image]

The project is about an online sales store, that wants to set up a management tool to sell products, and to manage its products. This tool must include the following features:

- Identification module: identification of clients, managers, supervisors
- Sales module: make purchases for users
- Product Management Module: Adding / Deleting Products
- Statistical module: visualization of sales statistics

Functional Specifications

It is necessary to act on the application, to connect to the application with a user ID and password. To facilitate its use and in order to avoid any mishandling thereafter, here is the solution:

User Profile:

- The user will be able to visualize the products sold by My Online Races. The user can place an order, provided that he has registered with the site My Online Races.

Manager profile:

- The manager will be able to manage the products:

  - Add / Edit / Delete Products
  - Add / Edit / Delete category
- These data insertions can be made using CSV or XML files, but also through various forms on the website.
- The manager will be able to view the sales statistics.

Supervisor Profile:

- The supervisor can add managers whose roles are specified above.
- The supervisor will be able to view the sales statistics.
- The supervisor will be able to view all the actions performed by the managers, a sort of audit trail.

Well I wish to know already if you have remarks about my design. As well as I have a confusion for several methods, for example adding, modifying and deleting a product. Should I put them in the manager or product class? Is the composition I put correct or should I remove it?

Comment: Your revised diagram is a little less confusing about the creation of the accounts, since only certain specialization of person can create an account;  However it is still inconsistent with the other objects:  for account, you have one account creating another, but for article and order, it's still the object that creates itself.

Comment: "Persistence" means that the data will be stored in a database.  When one start with object oriented design and databases,  it's a common approach to let each object manage itself in the database.  This approach is called [active record](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html).  It is acceptable, but it has some drawbacks, the main being that the domain object will be dependent of the database technology and the database implementation.  This is a strong coupling that will make changing the database difficult.

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick review of the diagram and advices

First some minor remarks about class naming:  `Ordered` should be called `Order`.

The [composition](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html?context=class-diagrams) between `Article` and `Order` is just wrong (not from a formal view, but from the meaning it conveys). Use a normal one-to-many [association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html?context=class-diagrams): it would reflect much better the real nature of the relation between the two classes.  Please take into account that a new article may exist without having been ordered, so it shoud be [`0..*` instead of `1..*`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html?context=class-diagrams)

`+belongs` and `+do` in the middle of an association are syntactically incorect.  You should use a plain triangle instead (or nothing at all).  The triangle should be oriented in the reading direction `Person   do |>   Order` and  `Article   belongs to |>   Category`

The methods seem ok. You do not need to add a suffix.

### How shall objects be managed (created/updated/deleted) ?

A more advanced concern is not about the diagram but about how you want to organise persistence (i.e. database storage):

- do you really want the object to be an **[active record](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html)**, that is an object that adds, updates and deletes itself (to the database) ?  It's simple to set up, works well, but makes the class dependent on the underlying database implementation and thus makes maintenance more difficult;
- or wouldn't it be better to use a **[repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)** for each object ?  In this case the repository acts as a collection that manages all the database operations. The domain object (Article, order, User, ...) then have nothing to know about the database, wich leads to more maintainable code.

But this is a broader architectural question. If it's just for a first experimental project with JEE, you can very well use the active records. It's simpler to set up.  Be sure however in this case to disambiguate the Add/Update/Delete on  `Person`, since it currently may give the impression that any person can add anyone.

### Improvement of the model

A final remark, again not about the diagram itself, is about the domain.  Your model considers that an `Order` is about a single `Article`.

In reality however, orders are in general about one or several articles: if this would also be the case here, your `Order` would become an `OrderItem` and the real `Order` would be inserted between `Person` and `OrderItem`. You could then make the relation between `Order` and `OrderItem` a composition (i.e: `OrderItem` is owned by `Order`, which has responsibility for creating its items, and the items have no sense without the related order).

Comment: Article composes Order not vice versa. So that just sounds legal. Pls. fix.

Comment: Also the operations are wrong too. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @qwerty_so It’s not a question of legality, it’s a question of semantic.  An article is not made of orders,  nor is it guaranteed that orders are owned by articles. It’s misleading to present it with a composition. Is there any argument that could justify that composition would me more accurate than a simple association ?

Comment: Composite aggregation is just about lifetime of objects. Not about ontology.

Comment: One more remark: in this model, it is considered that an order is about a single article. In practice, orders are in general about several articles: if this is also the case here, your order would in fact be an order-item and a class order would be inserted between person and the order-item. In this case, you could make the relation between order and order-item a composition (i.e: the order item is owned by and has no sense without the related order)

Comment: Yes. There are lots of errors in this design. The OP is a beginner and should be put on the right track. But he has to learn so much that we can not correct anything.

Comment: thank you I understand better what you meant. at first I would start with a simple design I made the changes you told me and later I would look even more in what you said for an automatic update